# How to redirect an URL dynamically in Apache with a RewriteRule (no php)?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have urls like:

```
https://test.com/blah/abc?aaa=bbb%3Fccc%3Dvalueineed%26stuffidonotneed%3Ddonotcare
```

And need to redirect (302) them to a different domain like:

```
https://test2.com/valueineed
```

In the incoming string, only the `valueineed`, which is a long alphanumerical string between `%3D` (encoded `=`) and `%26` (encoded `&`), is of importance to me.

Can this somehow be done with a rewriterule in an apache 2.2 vhost file?

**EDIT:**

The Url has an encoded Url as parameter and looks more like:

```
https://test.com/blah/abc?para=https://www.test1.com/%3Fp1%3Dvalueineed%26p2%3Ddonotcare
```

And the following characters are encoded in it:

```
%3F ' ?
%3D ' =
%26 ' &
```

I need to redirect to another domain with the placeholder "valueineed" that is a part of the encoded url as a Parameter as written above.